# Separar as linhas de arquivos em tokens - Python

Tags: python

Quero ler a linha de um arquivo e armazenar cada palavra ou informação em uma posição do vetor. Ex: "18-10-2015    00092    65534".
linha[1] = 18-10-2015
linha[2] = 00092
linha[3] = 65534
OBS: tabulação entre as strings

Comment: Primeiro mostre o que você já tentou fazer, segundo quais são as regras para tokenização? não da para alguém responder sem saber o que constitui uma "informação" no seu contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Para separar uma string utilizando espaços como delimitadores, você utiliza o método `.split()`:

```
>>> "18-10-2015 00092 65534".split()
>>> ["18-10-2015", "00092", "65534"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o metodo string.split() , http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

```
“split this string”.split(‘ ‘)
[‘split’, ‘this’, ‘string’]
>>> “split,this,string”.split(‘,’)
[‘split’, ‘this’, ‘string’]
```